# Problem with Infinity Scroll in mobile browser using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scroll, infinite-scroll

I've run into a bug/problem when i am trying to use infinity scroll in mobile browsers. I've made a project using vanilla js, and when the scrollbar goes to bottom it calls a function that fetching nextPage from an API( TMDB). Every time scrollbar touches bottom, it returns the next 20 items from the next page. So, in Desktop is all fine, but in mobile browsers, i am going to bottom and nothing happened. I think there is a problem with mobile browser topbar, but how i can fix it? Here is my code:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = document.documentElement;

  if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight) {
    showLoading();
  }
});
```

I would be appreciate if anyone can give me a hint about it.
Thank you!

Comment: Seems your code needs tough testing. Have you looked at [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)? Or you may try [some library](https://bashooka.com/coding/javascript-lazy-load-image-libraries-with-intersection-observer-api/)

Comment: just put some div on end of page. and then observer it by IntersectionObserver. When is visible(intersecting) then just load more what make this div not visible.  When user will scroll down then agin this div will be visible. (you can put some spinner in this div)

Comment: In addition to this you could also try to preload additional content while scrolling the page relative to the scrolling speed. May be [this example](http://taratsang.com/robbreport_gallery/lazy_load.html) will also help you

Comment: It was a part of a project for a company, assignment phase. i ve already sent the project for review,  and i was asked not to use external libraries or something else. It was pure vanilla js code. So, i asked here for personal interest now, about fixing it after the reviews process. I will check Intersection Observer API to check if it helps. Thanks for your answers.